# Labels in X-axis based on primary Y-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel scatter plot with two Y-axises (primary/secondary) and a common X-axis. Everything looks fine, except I want the labels in the X-axis to be based on the primary Y-axis. I want the labels in the X-axis to show exactly the dates that corresponds to the data points in the primary Y-axis. Nothing more, nothing less. Is this possible?

I have noticed that if I switch to line plot it adds a few options to format the X-axis. However, it doesn't seem to add the option connect the labels to the data points in the primary Y-axis.

Picture of the scatter plot:

[image: Picture]

The data is arranged like this:

```
Date          Data1     Data2
2000-01-05    0,5       10
2000-02-12    0,6       
2000-03-10    0,4
2000-04-15              15
2000-04-25    0,5
```

The primary Y-axis is based on the values in Data2.

I use Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

If you have irregularly spaced data points you will have problems, I think. The best you can do is to try and find a minimum data interval that would fit all the data points (e.g. if you have 10 30 45, then 5 is the interval), and then add data labels to each point on the graph.

Comment: Oh and make sure to use the XY scatter plot. Not the line plot.